# Submit an <input type="file" /> using jQuery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I have a `<div/>` tag which contains a file upload `<input id="file" type="file"/>` tag.  I want to post the contents of the `input` tag to a php page using `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` but how do I grab the contents of the `input` tag having its type as `"file"`? so I can submit it using the jQuery ajax functions?

Note:  My code doesn't have a `<form/>` tag yet.  I am not sure if its mandatory to upload files.  **Also i've seen some workarounds using `<iframe>` I want to know if this can be done otherwise.**

I don't want to use any plugins to do this.

Comment: this can be done with `<iframe>` / `java applet` / `flash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A byte stream can't be part of an asynchronous request.

In other words, you can't send data using AJAX approaches.

Comment: True. And I've answered that because he's thinking in jQuery $.ajax or any other approach using AJAX.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: This is not true. You can catch the data using "drop" event listener (e.g. on div) using `event.dataTransfer.files` and then create new FormData using `var fd = new FormData(); fd.append("fileToUpload", fileList[i]);`, create new XMLHTTPRequest and send the data: `request.send(fd);`.

Comment: @Julian I guess you're talking about HTML5. Feel free to edit my answer adding this info and I'll approve the edit for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can't send file through $.post...
you can use this link to uplaod file through ajax..
http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: Links to external site directly are not preferred on SO. You should provide in some contents first and then refer it.