# Submit a file as part of a jQuery post AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am trying to submit a file (together with multiple other normal POST data) to a webserver using a jQuery `$.post` request.

I saw questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197530/submit-an-input-type-file-using-jquery-post), but I believe it is outdated, as in the HTML5 era, things like the [Web File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) exist.

- I know that getting a File object can be done by `var file = $(#file_input)[0].files[0]`
- I know that reading the file can be done by creating a FileReader, such as `var file_reader = FileReader.new; file_reader.readAsText(file);`
- And then (once the FileReader's readyState is 2), the contents can be read using `file_reader.result`

This works great when working with text files. However, when I want to submit binary data such as pictures in this way, the content is changed and sent as text, corrupting it.

So for the question: How can I submit a file using jQuery's AJAX functions as part of the post data, without breaking its contents?

Comment: Have you heard of [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Answer (score 1):

Have you used readAsDataURL(file) method?

**Documentation:**

The readAsDataURL method is used to read the contents of the specified Blob or File. When the read operation is finished, the readyState becomes DONE, and the loadend is triggered. At that time, the result attribute contains  the data as a URL representing the file's data as a base64 encoded string.

With data base64 encoded you can send it and decode the data in backend.

**Hope this helps!**